# Apply a texture on a Box - jMonkeyEngine

Tags: textures, graphics, jmonkeyengine

How can i wrap a texture (for ex a 4x4 pixels) on a box (1x1x1) in such a way that the texture is repeated and not enlarged to cover all the surface.

```
 Geometry box = new Geometry("Box", new Box(1f,1f,1f));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Geometry box = new Geometry("Box", new Box(1f, 1f, 1f));
Material woodMat = new Material(assetManager, "Common/MatDefs/Misc/Unshaded.j3md"); //create a simple material
Texture tex = assetManager.loadTexture(new TextureKey("Models/guide.png", false));
tex.setWrap(Texture.WrapMode.Repeat); //This should set the texture to repeat.
woodMat.setTexture("ColorMap", assetManager.loadTexture(tex)); // with Unshaded.j3md
woodGeom.setMaterial(woodMat);                   // set the cube's material
```

Let me know if it works :)

(Note, I'm new to jMonkeyEngine myself, so this might not work. Good luck!)

NOTE: You might have to tinker with using:

```
box.scaleTextureCoordinates(new Vector2f(0.5f, 0.5f));
```

This will scale the texture to your liking.